# Memory footprint on windows

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-footprint

My C application on windows is running a for loop in which it dumps numerous entries into some data structure and then saves the same in an xml. Now, i want to know the memory footprint it is taking to do the same. Are there any tools available?

Answer (score 2):

Task Manager is the way I do it. It's simple and easy.

But it only works if you're trying to measure very large memory footprints. But applications with large footprints are probably the only cases where you'd need to measure the usage anyway.

If you want to measure memory usage accurate to the byte, I would just build a simple wrapper around `malloc()` and `free()` that increments some global value. (if the app is threaded, a lock might also be needed)

Comment: I also use Process Explorer. It's basically Task Manager on steroids. :)

Comment: Yeah, right!! Does memory footprint map to physical memory or virtual memory?

Comment: Both can be used. Virtual memory is probably more accurate though. You wanna look at the "Commit Size" and "Working Size" columns. "Commit Size" is for virtual memory and "Working Size" is for physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager is one way to do it. I prefer [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) because it gives a lot more info than Task Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the information!! I will use Process Explorer and see. One more query:Does memory footprint maps to physical memory or virtual memory?

Comment: If you go to properties of the process you can see both.